# Chatbot with map/location picker

Tags: botframework, bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am planning to build a chat bot using either azure framework composer, aws lex or google dialogflow but none seem to offer an easy way to have a map/location picker. It should be an straight forward interaction with user where based on a button click the user can then pick the  precise location from the map.
Has anyone done something like that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that any pure NLU framework is going to offer you that level of functionality.

The true purpose behind the likes of Amazon Lex, Google Diaglogflow is to perform intent detection and classification. It is up to the developer to build out the desired functionality associated with each of the configured intents.

What it may practically come down to is presenting the chat user with a map/location popup within the chat widget. The user could then select their current/desired location which gets sent back to the NLU framework for fulfillment.